# How to force Digikam 5 to have a specific tag in Awesome WM?

Tags: arch-linux, window-management, digikam

It used to be easy to make [Digikam appear on the correct screen and tag in Awesome WM](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/53a8f08e7398941bde8ac38e7858cd6c1188f5e0/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L431-L432) using for example `rule_any = { class = { "Digikam", […] } }, properties = { tag = tags[1][3] } }`. This doesn't work for Digikam 5.0.0. Instead, it always appears in the **currently focused tag on the first screen.**

The window manager class of Digikam has changed to be all lower case:

```
$ xprop | grep --color=none "WM_CLASS" 
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "digikam", "digikam"
```

Changing this is rc.lua only changes where the splash screen appears, but the main window still is assigned to the active tag on the first screen. How can I fix this?